# PHP Soap issue while content length is larger

Tags: php, apache, web-services, soap, nginx

We have developed a soap based webservice to post data to another third party webservice. It accepts 4 params. In one of the parameters it accepts an xml string for which no size limit restriction is put in place.

The webservice works fine in my local environment running on PHP 5.2 and Apache2. It works well with content length as long as 10 MB.

In my staging server we are running with nginx and php fpm.We have updated max post size and max upload filesize in php.ini and client_max_body param in nginx.conf to allow upto 50 MB.

But the webservice client keeps on loading in staging environment. Sometimes it gives 502 timeout and sometimes it gives soap error.

Can someone help me to understand the issue here?

Comment: Update : The data is forwarded by Nginx to php script.So I guess nginx isn't a bottleneck here.Possibly php-fprm?